# spring boot getVirtualServerName with java -jar and Tomcat 8. STS runs fine

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app the runs fine in eclipse.  When I build it and run it from the command line it fails with exceptions.

The problem appears to be a servlet version mismatch but I don't understand why.

It might also be important to note that I'm not using Maven or Gradle.  :-(

My run command:

`java -jar Demo.jar`

Exception:

```
Sep 15, 2015 7:30:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsContextListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:147)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsContextListener.contextInitialized(WsContextListener.java:39)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My MANIFEST.MF has these tomcat jar set in the classpath.  They are present and accessible.

`../../JavaJars.461248/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar
 ../../JavaJars.461248/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.23.jar
 ../../JavaJars.461248/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.23.jar
 ../../JavaJars.461248/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar`

Those locations look a little weird, but the files are there.  If I removed I get a different startup exception related to not having a servlet.

I think getVirtualServerName is in the 3.1 versions of the servlet which I think these versions of tomcat have.  Its confusing that these same files are in my eclipse classpath and I don't have trouble there.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: Your app must be loading the `ServletContext` class from somewhere else. Try running your app with `-verbose:class`. The output will tell you where it's coming from.

Comment: Also, is there any way to set the tomcat version as a startup argument or in code?  I know you can do it with maven properties, but I'm not using maven or gradle.  I ask because I might not be able to remove the servlet jar from my classpath in deployment.

Comment: No, Spring Boot will use whatever version of Tomcat is on the classpath (strictly speaking, whatever version of Tomcat comes first on the classpath).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andy answered in the comments.  verbose class loading allowed me to see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Careful with spring boot plugin, as it seems to adding to the classpath provided scope dependencies. I got this exception when emebedded tomcat was starting the web socket context.

The problem in my case would only happen using the spring-boot:run goal.

The reason being that gwt-user.jar package, that bundles an older

```
public interface ServletContext {
```

API without the method.

On the other hand, the tomcat was expected for the ServletContext class loaded to be the one part of tomcat-embedded-core-8.0.30.jar, part of the default configuration of spring boot.

Fixing the problem was a matter of tuning the spring-boot plugin with:

```
                      <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                                <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
```

The production jar as well as netbeans debug class run flawlessly, only with the plugin did this error take place.

In any case, it is the typical classpath vodoo exception. If you have a good IDE do a find Types and search for the ServletContext class across all dependencies you have. If you find different API's ... well.